# Unable to load type from assembly (C# Amazon lambda function)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

Since Amazon now supports C# to build AWS Lambda functions, i wanted to give it a try, but i get stuck when performing a test.

This is my simple class:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
//using Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json;

namespace MyTest
{
    public static class LambdaFunction
    {
        public static string Handler(Stream stream)
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

I compiled it using the .Net Core runtime. The result is a folder netstandard1.4 with the assembly MyTest.dll file and a MyTest.deps.json file. These compressed as .zip are uploaded to the AWS Lambda console.

In the configuration tab the Handler is defined as:

```
MyTest::LambdaFunction::Handler
```

But when i hit the TEST button, this is the error message returned:

```
{
  "errorType": "LambdaException",
  "errorMessage": "Unable to load type 'LambdaFunction' from assembly 'MyTest, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."
}
```

Note1 : before i knew i needed to use .Net Core instead of the full CLR, i got an error that the assembly could not be loaded, so i figured the assembly is compiled ok now.

Note2 : I've tried several argument-types (Stream and String are the only supported ones without custom serializer though) for the Handler method, as well as static/instance class or method or any combination, all to no avail.

Anyone who got this working already and can give me a few pointers?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Well, it's one of those days i guess....

The answer is, i forgot to include the namespace 8|

Should be:

```
MyTest::MyTest.LambdaFunction::Handler
```

Comment: I have the same problem and adding namespace does not help

Comment: @RomanAsanov post a question, show your Code. There has to be difference.

Comment: Thanks this helped, I am using terraform so i had to match the handler name to the namespace. AssemblyName::NameSpace.ClassName::FunctionHandlerName

Answer (score 10):

Had the same issue earlier today, I was able to fix it, here's the correct format that should be passed:

```
AssemblyName::NameSpace.ClassName::FunctionHandlerName
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried above all solutions but nothing worked for me.

In my case solution was to reduce length of combination of `AssemblyName::NameSpace.ClassName::FunctionHandlerName`. This combination was more than 128 characters long & lambda is deployed on windows.

Reducing length to **less than 127 characters** started working in configuration file.

Adding solution if someone else face similar issues.

Comment: OMG! Is that documented somewhere? This limitation is really annoying. C# assemblies usually are composed of `companyName.productName.[rest]`. In my case, it's `Joba.StockExchange.Rico.Robot.ResumeAuthentication::Joba.StockExchange.Rico.Robot.ResumeAuthentication.Function::FunctionHandler`, exactly 128 chars. SAM cuts the last `r` and I was wondering why lambda is trying to invoke `.FunctionHandle` instead of `FunctionHandler`.

Comment: @JobaDiniz Their documentation says the max length is 128 chars, so this seems to be a bug in their runtime. There's an issue about it [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/1642) and they reproduced it, so hopefully it'll get fixed eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this issue but setting the assembly name didn't fix it for me.

Here's what did, and yes ... it was a bug in my code.

The `LambdaEntryPoint.cs` immediately passes to the `Startup.cs`. If you have an issue in one of your dependencies or missing `appsettings.{env}.json` files, then it will throw exception.

Here is another way you can check if the app is working in production.

```
$ export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
$ dotnet run
```

In my case, was a missing `appsettings.{env}.json` file that was set to require. Unfortunately, lambda gives you a very anonymous error, but the fault could be in your `Startup.cs` in production.

This won't help most people but 1% that overlooked something simple...

Answer (score 0):

My problem was an architecture mismatch. The Lambda was set to `arm64` but the generated package was `x86_64` which I noticed when I looked at the output of `dotnet lambda package`. The `--runtime` was set to `linux-x64`.

Using `dotnet lambda package -farch arm64` solved it.

---

The output of `dotnet lambda help package`:

```
Amazon Lambda Tools for .NET Core applications (5.2.0)
Project Home: https://github.com/aws/aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli, https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet

package:
   Command to package a Lambda project either into a zip file or docker image if --package-type is set to "image". The output can later be deployed to Lambda with either deploy-function command or with another tool.

   dotnet lambda package [arguments] [options]
   Arguments:
      <ZIP-FILE> The name of the zip file to package the project into
   Options:
      --disable-interactive                   When set to true missing required parameters will not be prompted for.
      --region                                The region to connect to AWS services, if not set region will be detected from the environment.
      --profile                               Profile to use to look up AWS credentials, if not set environment credentials will be used.
      --profile-location                      Optional override to the search location for Profiles, points at a shared credentials file.
      --aws-access-key-id                     The AWS access key id. Used when setting credentials explicitly instead of using --profile.
      --aws-secret-key                        The AWS secret key. Used when setting credentials explicitly instead of using --profile.
      --aws-session-token                     The AWS session token. Used when setting credentials explicitly instead of using --profile.
      -pl    | --project-location             The location of the project, if not set the current directory will be assumed.
      -cfg   | --config-file                  Configuration file storing default values for command line arguments.
      -pcfg  | --persist-config-file          If true the arguments used for a successful deployment are persisted to a config file.
      -c     | --configuration                Configuration to build with, for example Release or Debug.
      -f     | --framework                    Target framework to compile, for example netcoreapp3.1.
      -farch | --function-architecture        The architecture of the Lambda function. Valid values: x86_64 or arm64. Default is x86_64
      --msbuild-parameters                    Additional msbuild parameters passed to the 'dotnet publish' command. Add quotes around the value if the value contains spaces.
      -fl    | --function-layers              Comma delimited list of Lambda layer version arns
      -pl    | --project-location             The location of the project, if not set the current directory will be assumed.
      -cfg   | --config-file                  Configuration file storing default values for command line arguments.
      -pcfg  | --persist-config-file          If true the arguments used for a successful deployment are persisted to a config file.
      -o     | --output-package               The zip file that will be created with compiled and packaged Lambda function.
      -dvc   | --disable-version-check        Disable the .NET Core version check. Only for advanced usage.
      -pt    | --package-type                 The deployment package type for Lambda function. Valid values: image, zip
      -it    | --image-tag                    Docker image name and tag in the 'name:tag' format.
      -df    | --dockerfile                   The docker file used to build the image. Default value is "Dockerfile".
      -dbo   | --docker-build-options         Additional options passed to the "docker build" command.
      -dbwd  | --docker-build-working-dir     The directory to execute the "docker build" command from.
      --docker-host-build-output-dir          If set a "dotnet publish" command is executed on the host machine before executing "docker build". The output can be copied into image being built.
```

Answer (score -2):

I also got this error message. In my case I'd called my function 'HelloLambda' but then copied some code which started:

namespace Calculator.

Changing that to

namespace HelloLambda

solved the problem